# How to save multiple images in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have selected multiple frames from browser. It is working perfectly as cover file for my project in video Steganography.

After embedding text in cover frames (multiple frames) I want to save these frames as stego images, but in my case it saves only the last image.

Here is the code:

```
[fn, pn,fi] = uigetfile('*.jpg*','Select the Cover Image','Multiselect','on');

coln=size(fn);

numberfile=coln;

for i=1:numberfile

    fn(i);

    entirefile=fullfile(pn,fn{i});

    fid=fopen(entirefile);

    fclose(fid);
end

I = imread([pn,fn{i}]);

pix=I(:);   

J = reshape(pix,size(I)); 

%till here is working fine

%this code below it problem when I save Stego image it save only last image

[fn, pn] = uiputfile('*.png', 'Save Stego Image');

imwrite(J,[pn,'\',fn],'png');
```

Comment: Try rephrasing and reformatting your answer, currently it is very unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may apply the saving operation in a `for` loop as follows:

```
[fn, pn,fi] = uigetfile('.jpg','Select the Cover Image','Multiselect','on');

coln = size(fn, 2);

numberfile = coln;

for i = 1:numberfile
    fn(i);

    entirefile = fullfile(pn, fn{i});

    fid = fopen(entirefile);

    fclose(fid);
end

for i = 1:numberfile
    I = imread([pn, fn{i}]);

    pix = I(:);

    J = reshape(pix, size(I));

    [out_fn, out_pn] = uiputfile('*.png', 'Save Stego Image');

    imwrite(J, [out_pn, '\', out_fn], 'png');
end
```

---

Note:
I replaced:

```
[fn, pn] = uiputfile('*.png', 'Save Stego Image');`
```

With:

```
[out_fn, out_pn] = uiputfile('*.png', 'Save Stego Image');
```

You want to keep (not overriding) `fn` and `pn` from the reading stage.

Comment: Sir i want to save this Stego image in specific folder and save filename automatic all the frame with different number or name( for example like 1.png, 2.png , 3.png ........ automatic it will save without manual enter the filename )

Comment: You can set file name as follows: `file_name = [sum2str(i), '.png'];`

Comment: That is not my question Sir.Suppose I have select cover file like 10 frames then I embedded this frame with text and after embedded I want this 10 frame to save as stego image in one folder. Sa that every frame I have to assign a unique file name to avoid conflict. Now my question will come I want all those 10 frame to save automotic in one folder and file name will assign automatic all 10 frames with unique number like 1.png,2.png......10.png.

Comment: **1.** Remove `uiputfile` from loop. **2.** Add code `folder_name = uigetdir` (select folder) before loop. **3.** Inside loop add `file_name = [sum2str(i), '.png'];` and use `imwrite(J, [folder_name, '\', file_name], 'png');`